# Battery setup to power UVC bulb with 12 V DC at 1 A

Tags: batteries, design, battery-operated, uv

So, I'm looking to power this UVC bulb kit:

[image: Picture of bulb kit]

The device size overall needs to be pretty small. (I'm trying to mount the bulb in the top of a cup-shaped housing. Ideally, the battery supply would be small enough to fit on/in a device about the size of a large solo type cup. (Actually, it would be acceptable to mount the battery pack externally, but this would have to be on the wall where the device is going to be mounted, with about a 3 foot distance.)

Cost is an issue as well, so nothing crazy.

I saw the option of using a 8-pack holder for AA batteries in series to get 12V. Will these support 1A? What kind of lifespan could I expect from such a configuration on this bulb?

Are there any other, better options?

EDIT: Manufacturer's website link, so you can view the specs and more info if needed:

[Manufacturer's website](http://www.rexim.com/pages/ccfl/mccuv.html)

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use batteries rather than a mains supply, since this is to be mounted on a wall? Is there no access to mains?

Comment: We can't guarantee access to mains, but it could be possible. We are still in the early design stages.

Comment: To clarify, we intend to use the device to clean water fountain nozzles. Some water fountains are located with access to a mains line, but others are not.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the added information and it makes sense, now. So you are not sterilizing the water leading up to the nozzle, but instead just sterilizing the exterior surfaces of the nozzle where people may be in contact? (I'd still be worried about what happens as microbes are pulled back into the mechanism when the faucet is turned off.)

Comment: Correct. We are doing surface sanitation, not water purification.

Comment: This is a mercury vapor lamp, right?

Comment: I think? It does contain mercury.

Comment: Check my edit to the question.

Comment: Thanks. I use mercury vapor lamps all the time. I used them to erase the old windowed EPROMs and I used mercury-argon lamps for calibrating spectrophometers for wavelengths (when working in the roughly visible range, anyway.)

Comment: Okay, so thoughts on power?

Comment: Well, I do have the obvious ones. I think you are using the right kind of lamp. It just needs a fair bit of energy. Easy to compute: \$12\:\textrm{V}\:\cdot\:600\:\textrm{mA}\:\cdot\:2\:\textrm{s}=14.4\:\textrm{J}\$. Assuming (8) AA alkalines, which at the currents you are discussing will yield about \$5000\:\textrm{J}\$ each, I'd guess you might get about 2500 uses before the batteries are dead. Just keep in mind that the intensity of the bulb may diminish over time and may need more time to achieve similar results. So perhaps even fewer uses? I'd plan 1000 uses to be safe.

Comment: We are just building a prototype, so that is probably good enough for what we want.

Comment: As a side note, what would be the recommended solution for limiting the timing? We would want to limit the product to run for the 2 seconds when the button is pressed, ideally. (Preferably with a way to change this time if we decide we want 3 seconds instead to be safe, but this is not mandatory). What is the simplest way to implement something like that?

Comment: I'll write up an answer for that. Very simple, really. Don't forget to send my royalty checks!

Comment: Haha, I'll be certain to if I end up taking anything to market (not likely, just a course project). I'm a software engineering student yet somehow find myself working out of my field entirely. Go figure.

Comment: One question. Do you want it re-triggerable? Or do you want to be forced to wait out the period before you can push the button again?

Comment: Either solution is acceptable; whichever is simpler would probably be best, but if I had to pick, I'd prefer to make the user wait.

Comment: Just a note. The tube itself has a datasheet that reads \$5\:\textrm{mA}\$ and a starting voltage of \$380\:\textrm{V}\$. Their included circuit seems a bit on the inefficient side to me, if their specs are right.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: \$380\:\textrm{V}\cdot 5\:\textrm{mA}= 1.9\:\textrm{W}\$. But \$12\:\textrm{V}\cdot 600\:\textrm{mA}=7.2\:\textrm{W}\$. That's under 30%. Not exactly efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a schematic that is not re-triggerable but can be used as a 2 second timed lamp circuit. I've included a D45H11 because they are in TO-220 packages, are cheap, available everywhere, and can deliver a ***lot*** of current while maintaining a decent \$\beta\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdZ44s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Feel free to lower the value of \$R_2\$ a little, if you want to supply more base current into \$Q_1\$ (if the lamp needs a lot of current then the base needs more drive current.)

Adding re-triggerability requires the addition of two diodes. But I didn't add them since you'd prefer it without that feature.

Also note that although the schematic shows a bulb/lamp, I really mean your entire lamp + circuit to go there. I don't know how long your HV circuit itself takes to stabilize and fire the lamp. But you can adjust the timing as needed.

The timing is determined by the two parts in the dashed box; \$C_1\$ and \$R_3\$. Adjust these a little to adjust the timing.

You can also use a BAV99 instead of \$D_1\$ and \$D_2\$.

Answer (score 0):

UV lamps with sufficient wattage to kill germs needs to be xenon or mercury type tube with HV inverters such as this which runs off 12V with ? Amps or many UV LEDs with low voltage similar power for an array. UV LEDs are likely to cost more with enough power and neither suitable for cheaper batteries than a LiPo pack and necessary current regulator for LEDs and pack charger and heatsink.   This not like some cheap flashlight unless you are designing with experience for high volume and high quality.

Comment: This manufacturer says 1A needed, but the specs sheet says 0.6 A.

Comment: Also, we already have solid data that shows that the bulb in question is more than enough to fill our germicidal needs. We are looking at a 2 second kill time max.

Comment: So in other words, we will only be running the bulb for a couple seconds at a time. Are you saying it won't be possible to do with our scale needs?

Comment: Hold up for a moment. Are we talking about an LED here? I thought otherwise. 254nm is a mercury line.

Comment: It is not an LED.

Comment: I know that UV LEDs are an alternative solution as my former colleague manages the engineering for this product. This user has zero specs for Lumens, Watts or power source

Comment: LED is an option, but if I understand, they are fairly expensive and large. Electrical stuff isn't my field, so I'm a little out of my element here.

Comment: Then find the watt rating from supplier

Comment: @TonyStewart I have posted a link to the supplier website containing specifications for the bulb and the inverter that it needs to be connected to.

Comment: You should buy one and test it for power consumption. Startup surge power may be high to generated the reactive energy stored in transformer and capacitors when only used for short bursts. Then decide time needed between charges then from those results. Only then can you spec a suitable source of power to meet long term cost target, based on Ah rating using 20 hr std.  then derated if consumed faster.